# AngularJS - how to start best in 2016?

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, material-design, angular, angular-material

I just starting to learn **AngularJS** (Version 1.5.0) with **Material Design for Angular** - damn looks so freaking sweet :)
For building and deployment i use **Gulp** to automate my tasks.

So far so good, but while googling my way to more questions i found Frameworks like MEAN Stack, Meteor, lumX, Ionic and many many more.
Im wondering if its better to start with one of the Frameworks or if Gulp + AngularJS + Material Design for Angular is just fine.

Before i played a bit with Foundation for Apps which looks sweet too but i really like the look and feel from Material Design. Before i used Zurb Foundation for my Responsive Webdesign Projects but consider to jump to Material Design (which is based on FlexBox) even i miss support for some older browsers.

So im bit confused if im wasting time to learn Angular Version 1 now and better straight jump to **Angular2** beta. My concern is that i may run in a lack of documentation and help. Also i have to learn more about **ES6** (which is necessary in the next time anyway but makes it more hard to start). I guess lot of the stuff i will learn from Angular v1 i can later on use in Angular v2 anyway, or?

Another question for me as a Freelance Web Developer is if its not better to stick with Angular v1 for a while and learn more about it and later jump to Angular v2 when its out of beta. Because the goal is later to get into some projects and i can imagine that the companies stick with v1 for a while till v2 gets more stable.

For some starting projects i wanted to create a few Templates and Apps for my Wordpress Sites based on Angular with Material Design on a LAMP Enviroment. My Webspace sadly doesn't provide NOSQL databases yet so i guess i will keep coding on PHP / MySQL for a bit.

So in short, if you guys where in my place (experienced in Web Development but new to Angular) where would you start right now?

What **Frameworks**, **Extensions** and **Tools** do you recommend for **Application Development** with Angular?

From a business point of view when do you think will Angular2 be widely be used on live projects and is it better to start learning Angular v1 or go to v2?

Thanks for your replies.

Cheers bin2hex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about AngularJS V2, but I made some AngularJS V1 projects last year. Here tools I use to make my AngularsJS V1 projects:

As project generator:

- [Yeoman](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular#readme)

As depedency manager (included in Yeoman angular generators):

- [Bower](http://bower.io/)

As task runner (included in Yeoman angular generators):

- [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)

Set of prebuilt UI components based on AngularJS directives:

- [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/)
- [Angular Strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/)
- [Angular UI](https://angular-ui.github.io/)

Actually in my opinion is better use AngularJS V1 for production purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of giving a biased opinion, I'll just provide for you a few links of project structures that are being used currently that might serve you some guidance.

## https://github.com/TheLarkInn/angular-starter-es6-webpack (This one is Shamelessly authored by me).

## https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

## https://github.com/AngularClass/NG6-starter (I took some pieces from this repo to create mine).

I'd recommend looking into writing Angular in the 'Component Style' (like the above links). It is a new way to start out using Angular 1/2 for the future and at the least you can use these repositories as thought-provoking brain-food for your own standards.

There are also other bundling platforms such as Browserify and JPSM, however Webpack provides a lot of awesome out of the box functionality that makes Angular development really awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing is something you haven't considered. All that matters is that you get your html/css/javascript *to the browser*. Everything in-between is trivial and leg work.

Now that Angular belongs to google, they have started *very* rapid development to support developers of all sorts. Either way it's going to be very stable, and if you keep your code modulare and clean, it's easy to transfer. I would say just make something, make what you need, and keep working on it over time and as the framework evolves, and change your code to match. If you keep waiting for the next big thing nothing will get done, so it's better to choose a framework and stick to it.

I word my answer like this because your question is very subjective, and you should experiment and find an answer based on your needs. As a web developer, you have to learn many different languages anyway, so start with where you think is best, and grow as you figure out what you need.